# Where to find the comment of column in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, layers, attribute-table, column

I created a column with a comment but where do I find this comment later on?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find it under `Layer Properties → Fields`:

[image]

Comment: thank you, do you know how I can change this comment?

Comment: You cannot. The comment is not editable once created. You need to create a new field, write the comment you want, and then take a copy of the original field before deleting it.